# How do Kubernetes modules communicate with etcd?

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I know that Kubernetes has 5 modules: `kube-apiserver, kube-controller-manager, kube-scheduler` in Master nodes and `kubelet, kube-proxy` in Minion nodes. How do they communicate with etcd? Will they all query or set data in etcd? or only some of them do?

[The docs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/etcd/) said that etcd is only accessed by `kube-apiserver`:

> Access Control: give only kube-apiserver read/write access to etcd.
>   You do not want apiserver’s etcd exposed to every node in your cluster
>   (or worse, to the internet at large), because access to etcd is
>   equivalent to root in your cluster.

But some blogs and architecture figures from Google believe etcd is also accessed by other modules, like what [this blog](http://cloud-mechanic.blogspot.jp/2014/09/kubernetes-under-hood-etcd.html) said:

> The etcd services are the communications bus for the Kubernetes
>   cluster.  The app-service posts cluster state changes to the etcd
>   database in response to commands and queries.  The kubelets read the
>   contents of the etcd database and act on any changes they detect.

So which said is correct? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not kubernetes expert, but from what I know, you have various compents that talk with api server and the api server talk with etcd, in this way every nodes doesn't have access to etcd, { etcd } <-> { api-server } < { nodes }, in you node the only thing that you need is kubelet  and kube-proxy

Comment: Please read the blog and watch this video. https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/etcd 
This will really give you a great insight about etcd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The docs you linked to are correct -- only the apiserver communicates directly with etcd. The rest of the system components communicate with etcd *indirectly* through the apiserver.

Also note that the blog post you linked to is just about 2 years old, and it may have been accurate at the time, but the docs you linked to are for the current release of Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

The API server talks only with etcd and includes a built-in bastion apiserver proxy; enabling external access to ClusterIP services. No other modules except API server can't talk to etcd.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).